# How to fire change event of HTML element text using Javascript, in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an chrome extension, and having issue that even if I changed the element text, the submit button not enables as usual and other stuff is not processing as manual typing.

I'm trying to fire the text changed event to process the elements normal behavior of manual typing using following script;

```
var el2=document.getElementById("tmsg");
el2.innerText="hello world";
try{                                     
    el2.fireEvent("onchange");
}catch(error)
{
   alert("err:"+error);
}
```

However, the text is set, but getting following error

```
TypeError: el2.fireEvent is not a function
```

I'm looking for solution with java script, without JQuery solutions, but none worked for me.

Can anyone please point me what I'm doing wrong here, or better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because `eventTarget.fireEvent()` is a proprietary method used in Internet Explorer.

The modern and standard way to manually dispatch events, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) is as follows:

```js
// CREATE EVENT
const event = new Event('change', {bubbles: true});

// GET TARGET ELEMENT
const el2 = document.getElementById('tmsg');

// DISPATCH EVENT
el2.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you. using dispatchEvent eliminated the error. But still I could not get the thing work. I'm still trying to figure out the issue.